# MAUI preview 9 “VersionCode 1.0 is invalid. It must be an integer value.” error when updating Visual Studio 2022 Preview 6.0

Tags: c#, android, maui

when I upgrade Visual Studio 2022 to Preview 6.0 ,I built new project for MAUI and the current MAUI version is preview 9 when I tried to build the project for android , the following error appeared

> VersionCode 1.0 is invalid. It must be an integer value.

please advice

Comment: When you click on it does it redirect you to some where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the .csproj file. You will see that there is a field with a version "1.0", created with an earlier MAUI version.

```
<ApplicationVersion>1.0</ApplicationVersion>
```

Make it an integer by putting just "1"

```
<ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>
```

Comment: do you know if this is a bug or because it is just because of preview.

Comment: It's because of the preview. There might be some breaking changes between the preview versions. Some types are changed and also the structure

Comment: Ok the Version should be an integer, let's say 2. What about the VersionName (string) which should accepts anything like '2.3.0' ? Is there something planned in the .csproj file ? Because whe I import my .aab file on the Google Play Console the values received are 2 (1.0.0) and I would like 2 (2.3.0)

Comment: I am sure there is something planned but I cannot be sure. Also I don't know what happens if you set that in your android.manifest